# PHP/HTML echo a variable in a div

Tags: php

I have a div which works fine

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <fb:like href="<?php echo $link; ?>" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""> 
   </fb:like>
```

If I try to use an echo, I don't get the value of $link when I do this.

```
echo '<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:like href="<?php echo $link; ?>" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
</fb:like>';
```

likewise this one too. i cannot get the $link.

```
echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=208015255907895&amp;href="',$link,'"&amp;send=true&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=trebuchet+ms&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> '
```

Any help?

Comment: pls see the $link with the answer from @fender echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=208015255907895&amp;href="',$link,'"&amp;send=true&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=trebuchet+ms&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `<?php ... ?>` in an `echo`. Try:

```
echo '<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like href="', $link, '" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>';
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `echo '<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like href="'. $link. '" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>';` `.` instead of `,`

Comment: @Fender: `,` works too (remember, that `echo` is a language construct and not a function). The difference: `echo $a,$b;` is like `echo $a; echo $b;` and `.` is the common concatenation. http://ideone.com/hDbwq or http://ideone.com/89iww : Note, that in the first example the string `"Hello object:" is returned, but in the second one is not.

Comment: @Fender It doesn't matter in case of `echo`

Comment: @Fender Try `echo 'foo', 1 + 2, 'bar';
echo 'foo' . 1 + 2 . 'bar';` and you'll see why I tend to use `,` with `echo`. :)

Comment: oh yea... you are right. Never thought of it this way ;-) You never stop learning :-)

Comment: @KingCrunch: Thanks for this explanation and example. I see the advantages of using `,` in this case

Comment: @Fender will this work on this echo '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=208015255907895&amp;href="',$link,'"&amp;send=true&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=trebuchet+ms&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> '

Comment: why don't you try it?  i think you should remove the `"` around `$link`, just use the single quotes here

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like href="'.$link.'" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>';
```

you cannot add `<?php ?>` brackets into your `echo`

Answer (score 0):

you are messing up ' " and a new php tag

```
echo '<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:like href="'. $link .'" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
</fb:like>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
echo '<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <fb:like href="'.$link.'" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
 </fb:like>';
```

Comment: see this too. $link seems not to work '<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=208015255907895&amp;href="'.$link.'"&amp;send=true&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=trebuchet+ms&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> '